# How to get a direct link to .deb file of a package

Tags: software-center, downloads

I'd like to install an app from my Ubuntu Software Center, However it's a bit large to download (It's [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html) and is around 760 MB).

I'm current in an university where we have got a service by which we can submit an *direct* link to file and then with high bandwidth that file will be downloaded.

Now my question would be, How can I get a direct link to a package currently available in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: even texmaker on official site has only 8mb, so my guess is they don't have offline installers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a relative path to the .deb file in the output of `apt-cache show`:

```
$ apt-cache show texmaker | grep ^Filename
Filename: pool/universe/t/texmaker/texmaker_4.4.1-1_amd64.deb
```

`apt-cache policy` shows the repository of a package:

```
carvalho@S6-STI-N04:~ $ apt-cache policy texmaker
texmaker:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.1-1
  Version table:
     4.4.1-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
```

You only have to join the repository base URL (`http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`, last line in `apt-cache policy` output) with the relative path to the file:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/texmaker/texmaker_4.4.1-1_amd64.deb

Of course, you must repeat that for the package you want to install and all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Just visit this link http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux and choose your flavour.

Then you can install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i texmaker_ubuntu*.deb
```

But you should take into consideration, you may suffer from dependencies problems.

Also note that the size of the `deb` in the official  site is just under 13MB so with respect to what you say, this proves that there are many other dependencies.

You can check any package dependencies using `apt-cache depends package-name`.

```
$ apt-cache depends texmaker
```

Sample output:

```
texmaker
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libpoppler-qt4-3
  Depends: libqt4-network
  Depends: libqt4-xml
  Depends: libqtcore4
  Depends: libqtgui4
  Depends: libqtwebkit4
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: texmaker-data
  Recommends: aspell
  Recommends: ghostscript
    ghostscript:i386
  Recommends: netpbm
  Recommends: psutils
    psutils:i386
  Recommends: texlive-latex-extra
 |Recommends: <hunspell-dictionary>
    hunspell-an
    hunspell-ar
    hunspell-da
    hunspell-de-at
    hunspell-de-at-frami
    hunspell-de-ch
    hunspell-de-ch-frami
    hunspell-de-de
    hunspell-de-de-frami
    ............
```

Comment: So that software itself is around 13MB and it's dependencies are that large?

Comment: This is related to your system, mine needs only 7MB since most of dependencies are already installed